# Inserting a new line of text after matching a line of text (sed)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I need to insert a hidden HTML input tag into any form tag within a bunch of HTML files.

My idea is to search for any instance of

```
<form
```

and if found, insert a line below it that contains:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token" />
```

What's the best way to tackle this? I'm close with

```
sed -e '/<form/a\<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token"/>'
```

Comment: Why do you add `a` as replace part ? Do you need it ?

Comment: @Patryk a\ appends the text on the newline.

Comment: Well, somehow `\a` doesn't work for me. But `\n` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Here is how it's done:

```
find . -name \*.html | xargs sed -i '/<form/a\<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token" />'
```

Answer (score 1):

To add something below each `<form` you have to add `&`  to indicate that you want to keep the caught sequence (plus `\n` as you mentioned you need it) :

```
$ find *.html | xargs sed -ie 's/<form/&\n\<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token"\/>/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

This can easily be achieved with this perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bkp -pe 's|<form|<form\n<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="$csrf_token" /> |' *.html
```

-i is for in-place editing

.bkp creates a backup file with that extension.